# How to read a file's content from browser?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 and I want to read an excel file (multiple files actually) from the user HDD without sending the file to the server, just class instances with the data read.

Is it possible to do this? and if it is how could I achive this?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: If you don't need to sent it to the server, what does `asp.net-mvc` has to do with it?

Comment: Look into using a JavaScript way to do this e.g. http://codetheory.in/parse-read-excel-files-xls-xlsx-javascript/   Be careful though, as using JS to read files on a client's HDD could be a massive security risk. You might want to re-think this i.e. is this going to be on closed network? If so then go ahead, otherwise I'd recommend not doing this.

Comment: thanks @JasonEvans yes it is in an enclosed network but is it a security risk for the server or the client?

Comment: On the client. I might be paranoid here, but you always need to be careful that some clever so-and-so doesn't manage to compromise your site, which could mean that accessing the client's HDD opens up an attack window.

Comment: How does user choose these files?

Comment: @LukLed He will select a folder and then with checkboxes select some excel (only excel) files for whitch to send data to the server. That's sort of the plan

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu I suggest you remove the f-word from your comment, as it might offend other users :) As your website will run on a private network, you're less likely to encounter a saboteur who will try any funny business. So you should be fine in that case.